# How to get all files from external sdcard and phone storage (internal with mobile memory)?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I try to get all files from mobile (both external sdcard and phone storage (internal with mobile memory)).

i try with this code `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. but from this i only able to get sd-card files not phone storage.

please help how can i get both memory location path or files.

Comment: You could start from the root of the filesystem `/`, but unless you do that as root you will not have permission to read all the files.

Answer (score 1):

```
File file[] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();
    recursiveFileFind(file);

public void recursiveFileFind(File[] file1){
int i = 0;
String filePath="";
     if(file1!=null){
    while(i!=file1.length){
        filePath = file1[i].getAbsolutePath();
            if(file1[i].isDirectory()){
                    File file[] = file1[i].listFiles();
            recursiveFileFind(file);
            }
        i++;
        //Log.d(i+"", filePath);
    }
  }
}
```

> If this is not work then in below code u can give external path and
>
> ## get all files.

```
private void getAllFilesOfDir(File directory) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Directory: " + directory.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");

    final File[] files = directory.listFiles();

    if ( files != null ) {
        for ( File file : files ) {
            if ( file != null ) {
                if ( file.isDirectory() ) {  // it is a folder...
                    getAllFilesOfDir(file);
                }
                else {  // it is a file...
                    Log.d(TAG, "File: " + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i know this method and from this method i already took all files but when sdcard is present in mobile then then Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() gives sdcard absolute path but now i also want to get all files from phone storage also. how can i get phone storage path ??

Comment: File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

Comment: File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();

Answer (score 0):

This code will give internal files.

```
    String[] SavedFiles;
    ArrayList<String> arrList;
    SavedFiles = getApplicationContext().fileList();


   arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
   if(SavedFiles != null)
          {
              for(int i=0; i<SavedFiles.length; i++)
              {
                  arrList.add(SavedFiles[i]);
              }


          }
```

Comment: its not giving anything